# Reverse x-axis factor levels of mcmc areas after coord_flip

Tags: r, ggplot2, mcmc

I have a data frame of draws from a Bayesian posterior distribution for three different variables, and I would like to plot them as `mcmc_areas`.

When I do, the variable names are on the y axis and the draw values are on the y axis. When I use `coord_flip` to switch the variable names to the x axis, they are reversed.

The other solutions I have seen involve modifying the original dataset or the aes in ggplot to include factor levels, which my data don't have.

How can I reverse the order of the variable names on the x-axis so they read var1, var2, var3 from left to right?

[image]

```
library(bayesplot)
library(ggplot2)

var1 <- c(-0.06002548, -0.02066638, -0.04869878, -0.03085879, -0.04363278, -0.04427182)
var2 <- c(-0.011345631, -0.033393275, -0.037143247, -0.012890959, -0.031249614, -0.001547747)
var3 <- c(-0.05907443, -0.06544918, -0.05831428, -0.04964141, -0.05206038, -0.05726436)

df <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

plot <- mcmc_areas(test, pars = c("var1","var2","var3"),
                   point_est = "mean",
                   prob = .95)
ggtest <- plot + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to reverse order in which you pass your variables to `mcmc_areas` to get the desired order after flipping:

```r
library(bayesplot)
library(ggplot2)

mcmc_areas(df, pars = rev(c("var1","var2","var3")),
           point_est = "mean",
           prob = .95) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Second option would be to set the desired order via the `limits` argument of `scale_y_discrete`. Note. Doing so slightly changes the look of the plot. To fix that I set the `expand` argument equal to values set by `mcmc_areas` which I extracted from `plot$scales$scales[[1]]$expand`.

```r
mcmc_areas(df, pars = c("var1","var2","var3"),
           point_est = "mean",
           prob = .95) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = c("var1","var2","var3"), expand = c(0.1, 0, 0.1, 0.666666666666667))
#> Scale for 'y' is already present. Adding another scale for 'y', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]